# Is there a Drush command to check the distribution version?

Tags: drush, distributions

Just that, Is there a Drush command to check the distribution version?

Let's say I have installed the commerce_kickstart distributionn, how do I check the version of this distribution with Drush?

this one doesn't work:

> drush pmi commerce_kickstart

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no.

Since `commerce_kickstart` is not a module, but a profile, the *drush* commands for getting info about a module (e.g.):

```
drush pm-info commerce_kickstart
drush pm-list | grep commerce_kickstart
```

will not work.

Comment: This is what I usually do, but it is time wasting. Also to mention that I need to check the Commerce Kickstart distribution version (which is 7.x-2.6), not the Drupal version (7.22).

Answer (score 4):

Try using drush [core-requirements](http://drush.ws/#core-requirements) command. It returns the status report in table form, and the information you want should be about 3 or 4 rows down.

```
drush rq | grep Kickstart
```

Comment: Even better you can: 
`drush rq | grep -i 'install profile'` so you don't care what distro you checking..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the Drupal version then simplest is to run `drush status` from a drupal installation folder. That will tell you Drupal Version on the first line, no matter which installation profile you used to install it.

Comment: in this way I can see the Drupal version but not the Commerce Kickstart distribution version

Comment: The question is about distribution not Drupal it self.